# post method not posting data in the data base express js / node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend

**i m building an api for my website and the post method wont send data to mongodb it works from post man but sends empty feilds **

heres the code of express

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.static("public/js"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/invoice_db", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const fromSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    numebr: String,
    email: String
})

const toSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    billing_name: String,
    billing_address: String,
    addInfo: String
})

const takeDate="1995"
const invoiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    invId: {
        type: String
    },
    date: String,
    issue_date: String,
    from: [fromSchema],
    to: [toSchema],
    description: String,
    Ptype: String,
    quantity: String,
    amount: String,
    totalAmount: String,
    gst: String
})
const Invoice = mongoose.model("invoice",invoiceSchema)
const From = mongoose.model("from",fromSchema)
const To = mongoose.model("to",toSchema)
// const invoice = new Invoice({
//     invId:"abc12345",
//     date:"12 12 12",
//     issue_date:"10 10 10",
//     from:[{
//         title:"acb",
//         numebr:"12345678",
//         addInfo:"avi"
//     }],
//     to:[{
//         billing_name:"wo",
//         billing_address:"waha",
//         billing_extra:"kuch ni"
//     }],
//     description:"akakka",
//     Ptype:"v",
//     quantity:"2",
//     totalAmount:"25"
// })

// invoice.save()

app.get("/invoice-generateeee", (req, res) => {
    res.render("invoice-generateeee")
})

app.post("/invoice-generateeee", function(req, res) {


    // const from = new From({
    //     title: req.body.from_name,
    //     email: req.body.from_extra,
    //     numebr: req.body.from_address
    // })

    // from.save()


    const inv = new Invoice({
        invId: req.body.invId,
        date: req.body.getDate,
        issue_date: req.body.issue_Date,
        from: [{
            title: req.body.from_name,
            email: req.body.from_extra,
            numebr: req.body.from_address
        }],
        to: [{
            billing_address: req.body.billing_address,
            billing_name: req.body.billing_name,
            addInfo: req.body.billing_extra
        }],
        description: req.body.item_name,
        Ptype: req.body.item_type,
        quantity: req.body.item_qty,
        amount: req.body.item_rate,
        totalAmount: req.body.totalA,
        gst: req.body.item_gst
    })
    inv.save((err)=>{
        if (err){console.log("lmao noob")}
        else(console.log("done"))
    })
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

**here is the ejs front end**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qhYk.png)

**and here is the data base in which post nethod sends empty feilds**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulmIQ.png)

Comment: You should definitely strip your code to what is necessary to understand your problem. Is it possible that "lmao noob" is printed in your server logs? Maybe you should log the error itself or return it to the client. I assume that the JSON object sent by the client does not match your schema definitions. That's probably also the reason your postman request works.

Comment: Please add a description of your http request.
I believe you're sending the content in the wrong format, try adding app.use(express.json()) to be able to parse json requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your code as mentioned below:

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/invoice_db", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const fromSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    number: String,
    email: String
});
const From = mongoose.model("From",fromSchema);

const toSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    billing_name: String,
    billing_address: String,
    addInfo: String
});
const To = mongoose.model("To",toSchema);

const invoiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    invId: { type: String },
    date: String,
    issue_date: String,
    from: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'From' }],
    to: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'To' }],
    description: String,
    pType: String,
    quantity: String,
    amount: String,
    totalAmount: String,
    gst: String
});
const Invoice = mongoose.model("Invoice",invoiceSchema);

app.get("/invoice-generator", (req, res) => {
    Invoice.find()
        .populate('from')
        .populate('to')
        .exec((err, invoices) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(invoices);
            res.render("invoice-generator", {invoices: invoices});
        });
})

app.post("/invoice-generator", function(req, res) {
    const newFrom = new From({
        title: req.body.from_name,
        email: req.body.from_extra,
        number: req.body.from_address
    });

    newFrom.save((err, savedFrom) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        if (savedFrom) {
            const newTo = new To({
                billing_address: req.body.billing_address,
                billing_name: req.body.billing_name,
                addInfo: req.body.billing_extra
            });
            newTo.save((err, savedTo) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                if (savedTo) {
                    const newInvoice = new Invoice({
                        invId: req.body.invId,
                        date: req.body.getDate,
                        issue_date: req.body.issue_Date,
                        from: [newFrom._id],
                        to: [newTo._id],
                        description: req.body.item_name,
                        pType: req.body.item_type,
                        quantity: req.body.item_qty,
                        amount: req.body.item_rate,
                        totalAmount: req.body.totalA,
                        gst: req.body.item_gst
                    });
                    newInvoice.save((err, savedInvoice) => {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                        console.log(savedInvoice);
                        res.send(savedInvoice);
                    })
                }
            });        
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Note: You need some exposure on [How to write Javascript](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/15-rules-for-writing-clean-javascript-8e2b2b426515)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a body parser so that the body won't be empty.
The easiest way you can do that is by adding the next line next to the other "app.use" statements.

```
app.use(express.json())
```